# Linux root certificates auto-update

Tags: linux, java, certificate-authority

I have a CentOS release 6.8 (Final) server and a Java Web application deployed on Tomcat on that server.

The Java application apparently uses the certificates under `/etc/pki/java/cacerts`. At some point the app started complaining about some SSL errors. As I researched them it turned out that the certificates must be updated with `update-ca-trust extract`.

Authough executing this command solved my issue I want to:

1. understand what happened.
2. verify it won't happen again

That being said:

- Why at some point the certificates needed to be updated and the Java app complained about it?
- Is there a way to trigger the update of the certificates when they need to be updated? Or should I just run `update-ca-trust` in a crontab task? What are the best practices on managing those certificates?

I found an article on ["How to reset the list of trusted CA certificates in RHEL 6 & RHEL 7"](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003) but I am not sure if this is the best way to do the update. There must be a solution where I check *somewhere* if there is update and apply it.

**EDIT** to provide more context:

The Java web app breaks when it tries to access a web page and get some data from it.

Here is some stacktrace:

```
2016-04-27 18:20:28,835 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR com.my.service.DocumentService  - Error while accessing "https://www.somepage.com"
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        ... 257 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
        ... 129 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 135 more
```

Comment: You will have to provide more detail about what the specific error was to determine what happened.     Normally the rpm package, in this case ca-certificates, handles the updates via scripts.  Possibly your CA configuration deviated from this somehow, or the app needed something not in the default package.

Comment: I updated my question.